# How to select a specific agent from a population of agents in Anylogic?

Tags: java, anylogic

I have a population of 30 agents (`people`)  that their attributes (`manhour` and `revenue`) are imported from an excel file meaning each row of the sheet represents an agent. I want to model the dependency between agent attributes(e.g. `revenue`) so I want to create a mechanism so that I could select a specific agent (e.g. agent number 1) from the population, check if some condition is true, for example if `manhour` of agent number 1 equals to `x` then change the `revenue` of agent number 5 to `y`. I am not sure what is the best technique to pull this off I would be glad to hear your Ideas. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Load your agents into a population, say `pop_MyAgents`

Then use lambda statements like `findFirst(pop_MyAgents, a->a.myIndex==1)` (if your agent has a parameter myIndex loaded from your dbase table).

To change revenue of a specific agent, you can use something like

```
MyAgent agentToChange = findFirst(pop_MyAgents, a->a.myIndex==1);
agentToChange.revenue = 5;
```

Seems like you need to catch up on some basics, many of the example models help with doing these kind of things. Also, check the help on agent populations, lambda statements...